# Celery "Received unregistered task of type"

Tags: python, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have read quite a few posts that are similar to this but none seem to make sense to me.

I am trying to configure a Celery PeriodicTask to fire every 5 seconds but I'm getting hung up on a Celery configuration issue (I think)

**comm/tasks.py**

```
import datetime
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task
def send_queued_messages():
    # do something...
```

**myapp/settings.py**

```
...
from comm.tasks import send_queued_messages
from datetime import timedelta
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_queued_messages_every_5_seconds': {
        'task': 'comm.tasks.send_queued_messages',   # Is the issue here?  I've tried a dozen variations!!
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        },
    }
```

The relevant output from my error logs:

```
23:41:00 worker.1 | [2015-06-10 03:41:00,657: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type 'send_queued_messages'.
23:41:00 worker.1 | The message has been ignored and discarded.
23:41:00 worker.1 | 
23:41:00 worker.1 | Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
23:41:00 worker.1 | Or maybe you are using relative imports?
23:41:00 worker.1 | Please see http://bit.ly/gLye1c for more information.
23:41:00 worker.1 | 
23:41:00 worker.1 | The full contents of the message body was:
23:41:00 worker.1 | {'utc': True, 'chord': None, 'args': [], 'retries': 0, 'expires': None, 'task': 'send_queued_messages', 'callbacks': None, 'errbacks': None, 'timelimit': (None, None), 'taskset': None, 'kwargs': {}, 'eta': None, 'id': 'a8ca18...227a56'} (216b)
```

Comment: the message body shows that the task invoked was `send_queued_messages` - however `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` has `comm.tasks.send_queued_messages` - see the docs on [naming](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names)

Comment: When I change CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE to send_queued_messages it still doesn't work, I get the same error message.

Comment: try running `celery inspect registered` to see if your tasks are registered correctly

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this exact problem, and it turns out the issue is not with the *name* of the task, but that the Celery worker isn't aware of your task module.

In other words, you have the name of the task correct (`'comm.tasks.send_queued_messages'`), which was generated by the task decorator, you just haven't told Celery where to look for it.

The quickest solution is to add the following to `myapp/settings.py`:

```
CELERY_IMPORTS = ['comm.tasks']
```

According to [the docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-imports), this determines the "sequence of modules to import when the worker starts."

Alternatively, you can configure your settings to auto discover tasks ([see docs here](http://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django)), but then you would have to namespace your task module(s), moving `comm/tasks.py` to `comm/comm/tasks.py`.

For me, the confusion came from Celery's automatic naming convention, which *looks* like an import statement, which led me to believe I was using `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE['task']` to tell Celery *where* to look for the task. Instead, the scheduler just takes the name as a string.

Answer (score 2):

I just run into the same problem. What I did wrong was that I didn't terminate one of my celery task properly (like the one named '**send_queued_messages**' in your case), leaving it run in background and keep sending task named 'send_queued_messages'. Which seems like not a big problem, as long as you still have that task in your code.

But in my case I modified my task name after that to something different (like '**comm.tasks.send_queued_messages**'). Which made the task named '**send_queued_messages**' become a '***unregistered task***', I think.

Below is what I did to solve:

1. kill all celery process: (grep 'celery' instead of 'celery worker' as indicated by celery documents)

> ps auxww | grep 'celery' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9

2. restart rabbitmq: (or whatever broker you use)

> sudo -u rabbitmq rabbitmqctl stop
>   sudo rabbitmq-server

Then the error was gone.

Comment: Phew. Thanks a bunch. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using below code in `proj/proj/celery.py` following [celery document](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html),

```
# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

and it looks pefect with tutorial,

Don't forget add your new app to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Answer (score 2):

Celery-beat was throwing me the same issue and nothing what was wrote above didn't help me.

I tried to insert this snippet into my settings file:

`CELERY_IMPORTS = ['myapp.tasks']`

although I didn't need it. But it helped me because new error log was appeared. In my tasks file I had an import of non-existing apps.

This can be caused by very confusion reasons... A lot of time there is a syntax error or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

See [the celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports) for an explanation on task naming.

In this case you need to provide celerybeat with a task name that it can find.

try this:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'send_queued_messages_every_5_seconds': {
        'task': 'myapp.tasks.send_queued_messages', 
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        },
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.  I tried the configuration that you suggested, and also the one that I have added in the post above.  I am still getting the same error.  Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?